# Derived DataTable has no DataSet

Tags: c#, datatable, dataset, datarow

I have a problem with `DataTable` and `DataSet`. We have created our own `ObservableDataTable` which can create a `ObservableDataRow`. To create the DataTable we use a `DataSet`. For creating the custom datatable we copy the schema of table which is created by the `DataSet`. But now i have the problem, that our new `DataTable` has no `DataSet`. This is the way we create the datatabe:

```
public class ObservableDataTable : DataTable
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the System.Data.DataTable class with no arguments.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableDataTable() : base()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create datatable from existing table and copy schema
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="table">Table which contains a schema to copy</param>
    public ObservableDataTable(DataTable table) : base()
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Get xml schema for copy purpose
            table.WriteXmlSchema(stream);
            stream.Position = 0;
            this.ReadXmlSchema(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the instance:

```
DbDataAdapter adapter = GetAdapter();
endOfResult = false;
command.Connection = connection;
countCommand.Connection = connection;
adapter.SelectCommand = command;
currentDataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.FillSchema(currentDataSet, SchemaType.Source, "ResultTable");

resultTable = new ObservableDataTable(currentDataSet.Tables["ResultTable"]);

observableCollection = new RadObservableCollection<ObservableDataRow>();
```

How can i assign the DataSet to the derived `DataTable`?

Maybe some one has done this before. Thank you very much!

Comment: Why can't you have the constructor accepts a DataSet rather like `public ObservableDataTable(DataSet ds)`?

Comment: This could be an idea too. I think about it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this, you can add your datatable to a dataset's tables collection,  and then your datatable has a dataset :

```
// Your code here
resultTable = new ObservableDataTable(currentDataSet.Tables["ResultTable"]);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(resultTable);
// Now your datatable have dataset : 
int tableCount = resultTable.DataSet.Tables.Count;
```

Comment: Solved the problem. Thank you very much! I do not come to the idea, that adding it to the dataset tables collection will automatically set the DataSet in the DataTable.